# Nivo Slider Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I have been using the Nivo Slider for a while now. I recently was working on a website, that had a nivo slider in it. So, i just copied the code over. Everything was working perfectly, until a couple minuets later, i looked and i had 4 images instead of three, and the first was blank, and all i saw was my background. The only thing i added after it was working was another picture, and this code for a news ticker.

```
<script type="text/javascript"/>
    var ticker = $('.ticker'),
    tickerInner = ticker.find('.ticker-inner'),
    tickerHeight = ticker.height(),
    tickerDelay = 6000,
    tickerSpeed = 1500,
    tickerInterval;
    tickerInterval = setInterval(function(){     
    tickerInner.animate({'top' : '-='+tickerHeight}, tickerSpeed, function(){
    $(this).find('p').first().appendTo(tickerInner); 
    tickerInner.css('top', 0); 
    });
    }, tickerDelay);
</script>
```

When i am in Google Chrome, i look on my console and this is what i get:

`GET file:///C:/Users/Hunter/Desktop/Websites/Team%20Fear%20Pro/undefined  jquery.min.js:4`

I am not sure what do do from now, and i have even tried doing it all over again, but will no luck. If there is anything else i can post to help out, just leave a comment. Thanks!

Here is my references:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="nivo/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like it might not be loading jQuery - but to be certain about anything, can you make a JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ to replicate the problem. Without the rest of the source code, I'm struggling. Thanks.

Comment: Will do, just give me a few moments.

Comment: Actually, with all the directories and things i am using, this will be quite hard. Is there anything you need that i can post? source-code wise

Comment: At the very least, put your index page on jsfiddle, maybe we can narrow it down from there. It may be because you are not referencing jQuery properly.

Comment: Did what? As in, edited your Q? Can you put your source code (at the very least your index page) into a fiddle. Thank you.

Comment: You can get rid of `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` as you are referring to `jquery-latest.js`

Comment: thanks. Also, @redditor i am going to try to start from scratch and see if i still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

When i did it from scratch, i went ahead and downloaded the new Nivo Slider, and it worked perfectly. I guess i had something outdated.